# Insert Rows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create the game OXO on WPF. I added the columns in my DataGrid but I want to add the rows without a value. When the user click on the cell, I want that the cell change his value to "X" or "O" depends on the user's turn. Please guide me. How can I manage it ?

This is my grid at the moment :

```
<Grid >
        <DataGrid   x:Name="grid"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Height="237" Width="300"
                    Margin="27,23,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FrozenColumnCount="3" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                    >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Width="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 rows and 3 columns in a grid and use checkboxes as content. And then you can style the Checkbox so that it displays X or O on toggle. Below is a sample xaml that I quickly wrote. Please let me know if it helps

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="txt" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="txt" Value="X"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="txt" Value="O"/>
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton"  IsChecked="{x:Null}"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton"  IsChecked="{x:Null}"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton"  IsChecked="{x:Null}"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton" IsChecked="{x:Null}"     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton" IsChecked="{x:Null}"     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton" IsChecked="{x:Null}"     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton" IsChecked="{x:Null}"     Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton" IsChecked="{x:Null}"     Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <CheckBox Content="RadioButton" IsChecked="{x:Null}"     Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataGrid` is not the right choice for this requirement.

I suggest laying out 9 buttons (with empty content) in a regular `Grid` and handling the click events from there. After a click, simply change the button content to `X` or `O`.

Comment: Thank you I will check it on the internet

Comment: lol, 'check it on the internet'.... That's what you have just done user3524214... Ether one of the above approaches is OK, personally I would go with Krishna answer and use a DataGrid....

Comment: @Monty can you justify the recommendation of datagrid?

Comment: @Gusdor first you justify why you consider a DataGrid not the right choice?

Answer (score 0):

OK here is an example that i have knocked up, @Gusdor i did use buttons in the end BUT not 9 of them!!....

The example checks for winning lines and stops the game as soon as one player has won, you then press the reset button to start again....

Start a new wpf project, call it noughtsandcrosses....Paste the following code into your MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Window
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:noughtsandcrosses" x:Class="noughtsandcrosses.MainWindow"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="386.551" Width="270.253">
        <Window.Resources>
            <local:GameOverToEnabledConverter x:Key="GameOverToEnabledConverter" />
        </Window.Resources>
        <Window.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </Window.DataContext>
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Reset" Command="{Binding ResetClickCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding GameOver}" Margin="0,272,0,0"/>
            <DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell"  ItemsSource="{Binding rows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="grid"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Height="257" Width="240"
                Margin="10,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FrozenColumnCount="3" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="75">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.GameOver, Converter={StaticResource GameOverToEnabledConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" Content="{Binding Cell1.State}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cell1}" FontSize="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="75"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="75">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.GameOver, Converter={StaticResource GameOverToEnabledConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" Content="{Binding Cell2.State}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cell2}" FontSize="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="75"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="75">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.GameOver, Converter={StaticResource GameOverToEnabledConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" Content="{Binding Cell3.State}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cell3}" FontSize="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="75"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Create a new class called RelayCommand.cs and paste the following code into it....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace noughtsandcrosses
{
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.  This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
    /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    ///</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    ///</summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

Create a new class called ViewModel.cs and paste the following code into it....

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace noughtsandcrosses
    {
        public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public RelayCommand<Cell> ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }

            public RelayCommand<string> ResetClickCommand { get; set; }

            public int NoughtsScore { get; set; }
            public int CrossesScore { get; set; }

            public int TotalScore { get; set; }

            private List<Row> _test;
            public List<Row> rows
            {
                get { return _test; }
                set { _test = value;  }
            }

            private Cell.CellState _turn;
            public Cell.CellState turn
            {
                get { return _turn; }
                set { _turn = value; }
            }

            private bool _GameOver;

            public bool GameOver
            {
                get { return _GameOver; }
                set { _GameOver = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("GameOver"); }
            }

            public ViewModel()
            {
                ButtonClickCommand = new RelayCommand<Cell>(OnButtonClickCommand);
                ResetClickCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnResetClickCommand);
                // Start with Noughts going first
                this.turn = Cell.CellState.Noughts;
                // Add 3 blank rows
                this.rows = new List<Row>();
                this.rows.Add(new Row());
                this.rows.Add(new Row());
                this.rows.Add(new Row());
            }

            private void OnResetClickCommand(string obj)
            {
                this.rows.Select(c => { c.Cell1.State = GetEnumDescription(Cell.CellState.None); c.Cell2.State = GetEnumDescription(Cell.CellState.None); c.Cell3.State = GetEnumDescription(Cell.CellState.None); return c; }).ToList();
                this.NoughtsScore = 0;
                this.CrossesScore = 0;
                this.GameOver = false;
                this.TotalScore = 0;
            }

            private void OnButtonClickCommand(Cell obj)
            {
                bool winner = false;

                if (obj.State == null)
                {

                    obj.State = GetEnumDescription(this.turn);

                    // swap user..... don't like this but for 20min wonder someone else can fix it
                    if (this.turn == Cell.CellState.Noughts)
                    {
                        NoughtsScore += obj.Mask;
                        this.turn = Cell.CellState.Crosses;
                        winner = CheckForWinner(NoughtsScore);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CrossesScore += obj.Mask;
                        this.turn = Cell.CellState.Noughts;
                        winner = CheckForWinner(CrossesScore);
                    }

                    TotalScore += obj.Mask;
                }

                if (winner || CheckForGameOver(this.TotalScore))
                    this.GameOver = true;
            }

            private bool CheckForWinner(int Score)
            {
                if ((Score & 7) == 7)
                    return true;
                if ((Score & 56) == 56)
                    return true;
                if ((Score & 448) == 448)
                    return true;
                if ((Score & 73) == 73)
                    return true;
                if ((Score & 146) == 146)
                    return true;
                if ((Score & 292) == 292)
                    return true;
                if ((Score & 273) == 273)
                    return true;
                if ((Score & 84) == 84)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }

            private bool CheckForGameOver(int TotalScore)
            {
                if ((TotalScore & 511) == 511)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
            public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

                DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
                    (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
                    false);

                if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                    return attributes[0].Description;
                else
                    return value.ToString();
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }

        public class Row
        {

            public Cell Cell1 { get; set; }
            public Cell Cell2 { get; set; }
            public Cell Cell3 { get; set; }

            public Row()
            {
                this.Cell1 = new Cell();
                this.Cell2 = new Cell();
                this.Cell3 = new Cell();
            }
        }

        public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private static int power = 0;
            public enum CellState
            {
                [Description(null)]
                None,
                [Description("O")]
                Noughts,
                [Description("X")]
                Crosses
            }

            private string _State;
            public string State
            {
                get { return _State; }
                set { _State = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("State"); }
            }

            private int _Mask;

            public int Mask
            {
                get { return _Mask; }
                set { _Mask = value; }
            }


            public Cell()
            {
                this.State = GetEnumDescription(CellState.None);
                this.Mask = 1 << power;
                power++;
            }

            public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

                DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
                    (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
                    false);

                if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                    return attributes[0].Description;
                else
                    return value.ToString();
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

create a new class called GameOverToEnabledConverter.cs (simply inverts a bool value to set the button enabled property) and paste the following code into it....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace noughtsandcrosses
{
class GameOverToEnabledConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
}
```