# Wpf DataGrid Squares

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Is there anyway to make the Datagird with Square objects instead of looking like a list?

something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you mean lik this... it put a square button in each cell

```
            <DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell"  ItemsSource="{Binding rows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="grid"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Height="257" Width="240"
                Margin="10,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FrozenColumnCount="3" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="75">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.GameOver, Converter={StaticResource GameOverToEnabledConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" Content="{Binding Cell1.State}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cell1}" FontSize="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="75"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="75">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.GameOver, Converter={StaticResource GameOverToEnabledConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" Content="{Binding Cell2.State}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cell2}" FontSize="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="75"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="75">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.GameOver, Converter={StaticResource GameOverToEnabledConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" Content="{Binding Cell3.State}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cell3}" FontSize="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="75"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

you will have to ramove the binding refs to get it to work... It was part of a bigger project here [Insert Rows in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371054/insert-rows-in-wpf/30405435#30405435)